# How to share folders inside VMWare virtual machine to host

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, ubuntu-10.04, vmware-player

I am running VMWare Player inside Ubuntu. Inside VMWare Player I am running Windows. I can share folders from my Ubuntu system to my Windows system through VMWare. Can I also use VMWare to share Windows folders to Ubuntu?

Comment: I usually approach shared folders from the notion of a portal: it is the one connection between the two OS.  In this case, I usually just share my Ubuntu (host) Home folder and then permanently mount the shared network drive in Windows.  On the windows side, I reroute all of the My Documents folder and its sub folders to the network drive, thus linking the portal.  But I don't think you can reverse share from the client to the host.

Comment: The newest version of VMWare Player that just came out says that it can do it, but I haven't figured out how.

Comment: Try to get a connection to a server in your ubuntu, you find it under 'locations'. Choose Windows-Share and put the IP\c$ (or IP\Share) of your virtual windows as 'server' and all that stuff credentials.